# NameError: uninitialized constant Sprockets::Rails::VERSION on pushing to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have an app which runs on local machine.

Rails 4.2.0

Ruby 2.2.3

I am getting the following error on pushing to heroku.  The app runs on local machine.

rake aborts with the error `NameError: uninitialized constant Sprockets::Rails::VERSION`

```
Counting objects: 1965, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (608/608), done.

Writing objects: 100% (1965/1965), 229.38 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 1965 (delta 1275), reused 1958 (delta 1272)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.3
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
remote:        Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
remote:        This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
remote:        In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4
remote:        Fetching git://github.com/derekprior/momentjs-rails.git
remote:        Fetching git://github.com/zpaulovics/datetimepicker-rails.git
remote:        Cloning into 'bootstrap-datetimepicker'...
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Resolving dependencies..........................................
remote:        Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions
remote:        Installing rake 11.1.2
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Installing minitest 5.8.4
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.0.0
remote:        Installing rack 1.6.4
remote:        Installing mime-types 2.99.1
remote:        Installing arel 6.0.3
remote:        Installing execjs 2.6.0
remote:        Installing bcrypt 3.1.11 with native extensions
remote:        Installing bootstrap_form 2.3.0
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.22
remote:        Using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing hike 1.2.3
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.11.3
remote:        Installing tilt 1.4.1
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Installing daemons 1.2.3
remote:        Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Installing eventmachine 1.0.9.1 with native extensions
remote:        Installing unf_ext 0.0.7.2 with native extensions
remote:        Installing fabrication 2.15.0
remote:        Installing google_visualr 2.5.1
remote:        Installing sexp_processor 4.7.0
remote:        Installing hashie 3.4.3
remote:        Installing json_pure 1.8.3
remote:        Installing libv8 3.16.14.13
remote:        Installing nested_form 0.3.2
remote:        Installing netrc 0.11.0
remote:        Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions
remote:        Installing phony 2.15.21
remote:        Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
remote:        Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
remote:        Installing remotipart 1.2.1
remote:        Installing safe_yaml 1.0.4
remote:        Installing ref 2.0.0
remote:        Installing faker 1.6.3
remote:        Installing validates_email_format_of 1.6.3
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.6.7.2 with native extensions
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing rack-protection 1.5.3
remote:        Installing warden 1.2.6
remote:        Installing mail 2.6.4
remote:        Installing rdoc 4.2.2
remote:        Installing autoprefixer-rails 6.3.6
remote:        Installing uglifier 3.0.0
remote:        Installing figaro 1.1.1
remote:        Installing sprockets 2.12.4
remote:        Installing haml 4.0.7
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing ruby_parser 3.8.1
remote:        Installing unf 0.1.4
remote:        Installing tropo-webapi-ruby 0.1.13
remote:        Installing therubyracer 0.12.2 with native extensions
remote:        Installing rails_12factor 0.0.3
remote:        Installing activesupport 4.2.0
remote:        Installing sinatra 1.4.7
remote:        Installing sdoc 0.4.1
remote:        Installing bootstrap-sass 3.3.6
remote:        Installing domain_name 0.5.20160310
remote:        Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Installing globalid 0.3.6
remote:        Installing activemodel 4.2.0
remote:        Installing clockwork 2.0.0
remote:        Installing delayed_job 4.1.1
remote:        Installing jbuilder 1.5.3
remote:        Installing phony_rails 0.14.0
remote:        Installing http-cookie 1.0.2
remote:        Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
remote:        Installing loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Installing html2haml 2.0.0
remote:        Installing rack-pjax 0.8.0
remote:        Installing activejob 4.2.0
remote:        Installing activerecord 4.2.0
remote:        Installing rest-client 1.8.0
remote:        Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Installing delayed_job_active_record 4.1.0
remote:        Installing delayed_job_web 1.2.10
remote:        Installing has_secure_token 1.0.0
remote:        Installing actionview 4.2.0
remote:        Installing actionpack 4.2.0
remote:        Installing railties 4.2.0
remote:        Installing actionmailer 4.2.0
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 2.0.1
remote:        Installing kaminari 0.16.3
remote:        Installing simple_form 3.1.1
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 4.1.1
remote:        Using momentjs-rails 2.11.1 from git://github.com/derekprior/momentjs-rails.git (at master@41e30d4)
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.0.1
remote:        Installing responders 2.1.2
remote:        Installing font-awesome-rails 4.6.1.0
remote:        Installing jquery-ui-rails 5.0.5
remote:        Installing haml-rails 0.9.0
remote:        Installing rails 4.2.0
remote:        Installing turbolinks 2.5.3
remote:        Using datetimepicker-rails 4.7.16 from git://github.com/zpaulovics/datetimepicker-rails.git (at master@36d21ce)
remote:        Installing sass-rails 4.0.1
remote:        Installing devise 4.0.1
remote:        Installing browser-timezone-rails 0.0.8
remote:        Installing fullcalendar-rails 2.6.1.0
remote:        Installing dateslices 0.0.4
remote:        Installing jquery-turbolinks 2.1.0
remote:        Installing jquery-datatables-rails 3.3.0
remote:        Installing rails_admin 0.8.1
remote:        Bundle complete! 52 Gemfile dependencies, 109 gems now installed
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Post-install message from rdoc:
remote:        Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
remote:        <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
remote:        = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
remote:        = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
remote:        >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
remote:        Post-install message from haml:
remote:        HEADS UP! Haml 4.0 has many improvements, but also has changes that may break
remote:        your application:
remote:        * Support for Ruby 1.8.6 dropped
remote:        * Support for Rails 2 dropped
remote:        * Sass filter now always outputs <style> tags
remote:        * Data attributes are now hyphenated, not underscored
remote:        * html2haml utility moved to the html2haml gem
remote:        * Textile and Maruku filters moved to the haml-contrib gem
remote:        For more info see:
remote:        http://rubydoc.info/github/haml/haml/file/CHANGELOG.md
remote:        Post-install message from phony_rails:
remote:        It now adds a '+' to the normalized number when it starts with a country number!
remote:        Bundle completed (61.53s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NameError: uninitialized constant Sprockets::Rails::VERSION
remote:        /tmp/build_ff86312346869b165736d37b1725f32c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6/lib/bootstrap-sass/engine.rb:11:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_ff86312346869b165736d37b1725f32c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_ff86312346869b165736d37b1725f32c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_ff86312346869b165736d37b1725f32c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_ff86312346869b165736d37b1725f32c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_ff86312346869b165736d37b1725f32c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_ff86312346869b165736d37b1725f32c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
remote:        /tmp/build_ff86312346869b165736d37b1725f32c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
remote:        /tmp/build_ff86312346869b165736d37b1725f32c/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_ff86312346869b165736d37b1725f32c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_ff86312346869b165736d37b1725f32c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:443:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_ff86312346869b165736d37b1725f32c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to fathom-reef-94288.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/fathomless-reef-94288.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/fathom-reef-94288.git'
```

I get the following error on performing `rake assets:precompile` on my local machine.  This is the same error I get on heroku push.

```
rake assets:precompile
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Sprockets::Rails::VERSION
/Users/azs/ror/maintr/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Are you able to precompile assets if you try to do it locally?

Comment: Marc, I tried rake assets:precompile locally and got an error message which is the same as the heroku message.  Will post the error in my post above.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an old version of `sprockets-rails` gem being installed. With Rails 4.2 you should be getting version 3 or later. But, in your case the bundler is installing version `2.0.1`. Some version of the gem [had this exact problem](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/131).

I guess the easiest way would be to generate a `Gemfile.lock` file on linux machine and force Heroku to use new version of the `sprockets-rails` gem.

Comment: How to force heroku to use the new version?  I specified version `sprockets-rails ~>3.0.0` in gemfile and it still installs `2.0.1`